# Reputation graph doesn't load with large range

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

If I look at my reputation graph with a large range, the bars don't appear on the chart:

[image]

However, if I select a smaller range, things seem to work fine:

[image]

It looks like anything under a year works, but any timespan over a year doesn't. I'm on Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m. No errors appear in the console.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated our CSS rules for the graph - this will be with you in the next build.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks :)

Comment: This still isn't working (on either Meta or SO). Has the next build been released yet, or is there some other problem?

Comment: @Mansfield - that build was out a good while ago. Looks like a regression somewhere.

Comment: Should I create a new post?

Comment: No, no need. I've removed the [meta-tag:status-completed], so this is still open.