# Reputation graph doesn't work for large selections

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

**Small** selection:

> [image]

**Medium** Selection:

> [image]

**Big** Selection:

> [image]

**Full** Selection:

> [image]

Odd isn't it. Once I drag for larger size, all the green bars simultaneously disappear. Quite perplexing.

Comment: Can you reproduce in different browsers? There used to be a bug where the graph wouldn't show up at all in newer versions of Chrome (that was fixed a while ago). The point is, sometimes these things are just isolated to particular versions of particular browsers.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207931/212780